# Alternatives to xrandr for HiDPI double screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a Dell Precision 5510 with a 3840x2160 screen, connected to a monitor with a 1920x1200px resolution. In order to use them together I followed what is suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays). In other words, executing:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --panning 3840x2400+3840+0 --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP1
```

However, I get several problems:

- The worse is my graphics card slows down a lot.
- Also, it sometimes freezes and restarts with no warning. This can be really dangerous if it continues to happen.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do, or what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: As a general comment: if your system freezes there is a driver / kernel problem. A properly working Linux (without bugs) should not do this.  Your system has Nvidia® Quadro® M1000M GPU?